# Cythonized Sutherland-Hogman algorithm

Tags: python, performance, numpy, computational-geometry, cython

I want to cythonise the [python implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping#Python) of the [Sutherland-Hogman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm). This algorithm updates a list of vertices according to pretty simple rules (being inside or outside an edge, etc.) but the details are not important. Here is the python version it accepts lists of vertices of polygons oriented clockwise. For instance those:

```
sP=[(50 150),  (200 50),  (350 150), (350 300), (250 300), (200 250), (150 350)(100 250) (100 200)]
cP=[(100, 100), (300, 100), (300, 300), (100, 300)]
```

and calculate their intersection:

```
inter=clip(sP, cP)
```

Here is the code found on rosettacode and slightly modified to return an empty list if there is no intersection.

```
def clip(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):
   def inside(p):
      return(cp2[0]-cp1[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (cp2[1]-cp1[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])

   def computeIntersection():
      dc = [ cp1[0] - cp2[0], cp1[1] - cp2[1] ]
      dp = [ s[0] - e[0], s[1] - e[1] ]
      n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
      n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
      n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
      return [(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3]

   outputList = subjectPolygon
   cp1 = clipPolygon[-1]

   for clipVertex in clipPolygon:
      cp2 = clipVertex
      inputList = outputList
      outputList = []
      s = inputList[-1]

      for subjectVertex in inputList:
         e = subjectVertex
         if inside(e):
            if not inside(s):
               outputList.append(computeIntersection())
            outputList.append(e)
         elif inside(s):
            outputList.append(computeIntersection())
         s = e
      if len(outputList)<1:
          return []
      cp1 = cp2
   return(outputList)
```

This function is excruciatingly slow for my applications so I tried to cythonize it using numpy. Here is my cython version. I had to define the two functions outside clip because I had error messages about buffer inputs.

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def clip(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] subjectPolygon,np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] clipPolygon):


    outputList = list(subjectPolygon)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1 = clipPolygon[-1,:]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2 

    for i in xrange(clipPolygon.shape[0]):
       cp2 = clipPolygon[i]
       inputList = outputList
       outputList = []
       s = inputList[-1]

       for subjectVertex in inputList:
          e = subjectVertex
          if inside(e, cp1, cp2):
             if not inside(s, cp1, cp2):
                outputList.append(computeIntersection(cp1, cp2, e, s))
             outputList.append(e)
          elif inside(s, cp1, cp2):
             outputList.append(computeIntersection(cp1, cp2, e, s))
          s = e
       if len(outputList)<1:
         return []
       cp1 = cp2

    return(outputList)


def computeIntersection(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] e, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] s):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dc = cp1-cp2
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] dp = s-e
    cdef np.float32_t n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
    cdef np.float32_t n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
    cdef np.float32_t n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] res=np.array([(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3], dtype=np.float32)
    return res

def inside(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] p, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp1, np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] cp2):

    cdef bint b=(cp2[0]-cp1[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (cp2[1]-cp1[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])
    return b
```

When I time the two versions I gained only a factor of two in speed-up I need at least 10 times that (or 100x !). Is there something to do ?
How does one deal with variable sized list with Cython ?
I do not know if this could be useful but my inputs are of fixed length.

Comment: Reopen your SO question.  `@prune` doesn't have any experience answering `cython` questions on CR.  Your SO version will get a lot more attention than this CR one.

Comment: Following @hpaulj comment I reopened it on SO.

Comment: I will close the one that gets the least feedback.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 5 → 2.

Comment: @jean If you open a new post and in the title add something like - Parallel or vectorizing methods?  I can likely post you some code changes that will get your required speed.  Be sure to note Python 3.5 Windows x64 so answers are relevant.  I think you could get what you need in a lot less code.

Comment: @Matt thanks are you sure you could parallelize clip more ? I am not interested in parrallelizing the for loop where I call clip it is just a toy example but actually clip is called in another cython function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some things which won't give you a speedup factor of 10 but might get another 2 or 3:

1. Only call `inside` once for each set of arguments. The inner loop calls `inside(e)` and `inside(s)` every time, and then assigns `s = e`.
2. Factor out `dc` and `n1`. `dc` is calculated in every call to `inside` and every call to `computeIntersection`; `n1` is calculated in every call to `computeIntersection`. But `cp1` and `cp2` change very rarely.

To get more speedup, it's probably worth looking at parallelisation. Lifting `inside` over `inputList` is completely parallelisable; mapping `(s, e, s_inside, e_inside)` to a suitable sublist of `[computeIntersection(e, s), e, computeIntersection(e, s)]` is also completely parallelisable, although possibly a bit fiddly. I don't know anything about parallelisation in Python, but [there seem to be options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9786102/573420).

Comment: Thanks definitely a good answer I will benchmark your solution and come back to you asap.

Comment: Thinking about it I do not think we can get rid of one of the inside because e is assigned to s afterwards.

Comment: @jean, you're thinking about it backwards. It's precisely *because*  `e` is assigned to `s` that you can reuse the result of `inside`.

Comment: I will get bak to you tomorrow with an updated version of the code and benchmarks.

Comment: I finally got it super nice comments !

Comment: do you know why the only numpy array version gives worse performances ?

Answer (score 3):

One important thing to mention - if you're cythoning a for loop through a range, you need to cdef the type of the index.

```
def pointless_add_slow(j):
     for i in range(120000):
           i = i+j
     return i

%timeit pointless_add_slow(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.71 ms per loop
```

New block in jupyter:

```
%%cython
def pointless_add(j):
     cdef int i
     for i in range(120000):
           i = i+j
     return i

%timeit pointless_add(1)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.98 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not change noticeably the becnhmarks.